# selecting values in same time period sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider Table Events

```
Date         Time         Duration        Event
1-1-2023     20:28:00     95              A
1-1-2023     20:29:00     60              B
1-1-2023     20:29:55     10              C
1-1-2023     21:12:00     2               D
...
```

Now i want to get entries happening in same time period, so for example activity A happens from 20:28:00 to 20:29:35, and activity B happens in time period of 20:29:00 to 20:30:00

So Event A and B have common 35 seconds and B and C has common 5 secs.

i want to get all events in common time period, is it possible using just sql query?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A,B  20:28:00\n
B,C  20:29:00

Comment: also the event column can be random

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dates are in the proper ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`, you can use a self join:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e1 INNER JOIN events e2
ON e2.event > e1.event
AND datetime(e2.date || ' ' || e2.time, e2.duration || ' second') > e1.date || ' ' || e1.time
AND e2.date || ' ' || e2.time < datetime(e1.date || ' ' || e1.time, e1.duration || ' second');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fmhumRAZ).

Comment: i think this works good when there are only 2 common time events, what if there are multiple? like A,B,C,D event sharing 5 secs

Comment: @AlokSaini you will get all the pairs: https://dbfiddle.uk/nyP0yjGi

Comment: on a table of 13000 rows, it returns 33 rows returned in 89660ms, too slow

Comment: @AlokSaini if you kept date an time values in a single column an not in 2 then there would be no need for concatenations which prevent the use of any indexes (which would help) to produce datetime values to be compared. Change your design.

Comment: Result: 33 rows returned in 78578ms, after merging datetime to 1 column and creating an index over it

Comment: @AlokSaini the difference in time is because of the merging of the columns. The index should be created on the column event (and perhaps combined with the new datetime column): https://dbfiddle.uk/lUGtdyhR Also, a table of 13000 rows is not considered a big data set, but what you want is to compare every row of the table with all the other rows of the table which means that you select from a dataset of 13000x13000=169000000 rows.

Comment: anyway to improve it further? table structure changes?

Comment: let suppose the data is time sorted, and could only compare next entryies till time+duration > next.time ?

Comment: so i added one more condition `and e2.event < e1.event+5` which instead of comparing each row to all other rows, compare it to just next 5 rows. result is good : Result: 33 rows returned in 62ms, removed merged calldatetime column and using concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, supposing you have index on date-time

```
SELECT *
FROM events e1 INNER JOIN events e2
ON  datetime(e2.date || ' ' || e2.time) 
    BETWEEN (e1.date || ' ' || e1.time)
       AND datetime(e1.date || ' ' || e1.time, e1.duration || ' second')
WHERE e2.event <> e1.event;
```

As @forpas says, if you kept date an time values in a single column, and have index on this column, performance will be better